# How execute every Javascript function(or functions inside a scope) with in a try catch block using a coding pattern/framework?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Sorry for the ambiguous question statement.

Detailed explaination
The requirement is to execute every javascript function inside try/catch blocks.
no. of functions = no of try catch blocks.

**example**

```
var module = function(){
    try{
        something();
    }catch(e){
        something();
    }
};
```

**Purpose of Try/Catch**

- To log all the point of failures in the code across all the browsers and devices.

**What I have tried**

- I tried creating a function which will be called using the `bind()` function so that i can replace the `this` attribute in the context. Code does not seem to work properly and consistently.

doing so for hundreds of function is not feasible and a good practice. can you please suggest some pattern/framework for achieving the same.

Comment: If you have to log all the failures in your code, maybe it's time to consider writing code that works ?

Comment: Yes thats the best practice i can think of. But the requirements demand the design to incorporate the try catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

> doing so for hundreds of function is not feasible and a good practice. can you please suggest some pattern/framework for achieving the same.

You don't need to wrap inner calls. Only higher level calls **that can actually handle the exceptions caught** should have try/catch blocks.  In other words, if a calls b, and b calls c, and b is wrapped in a try/catch when it's called in a, then so is c.

Comment: Following is the coding pattern that is followed.

`var Module = (function () {

  var privateMethod = function () {};
  
  return {
    publicMethodOne: function () {
      
    },
    publicMethodtwo: function () {

    },
    publicMethodThree: function () {

    }
  };

})();
`

So if we wrap the entire "var Module" in try catch it should solve problem.
But if we can find a pattern to wrap all the called function other functionality can also be achieved. 
like Logging the entry and exit for easy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

presently i am using the following code to achieve the problem statement.

```
x = function(x){
    console.log(x);
}

logger = {
    log : function(func,args){
    console.log("entering");
    try{
        throw "e";
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("the error ",e);
        console.trace();
    }
    func();
    console.log("exiting");
    }
}
```

To call the function we will have to do the following

```
logger.log(x,2);
```

it is still not a optimized solution but prevents me from repeating try catch blocks.